# Why do .columns method in pandas does not have any parenthesis ()?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

What is the difference between methods with brackets and without brackets in python? Is there any way to find which methods need to be used with brackets and without brackets? Examples with brackets are .mean(), .head(),  .tail(). Examples without brackets are .size,  .columns and so on.

**what is the difference between methods and attributes? what is the need for being two individual elements? How to identify whether it is an attribute or a method?**

Comment: A method without parentheses isn't a method at all, it's an attribute.

Comment: What is the difference between an attribute and a method?  Is there any way to differentiate them? How do I find whether it is a method or an attribute?

Comment: Read the docs. Or try it out. In principle, all attributes can be implemented as methods and vice versa. Would be nice if there where an obvious logic behind it in all cases, but that's not the case, imo.